# How to set class_weight parameter for cost sensitive learning?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, random-forest, binary

I'm dealing with a binary classification problem with a balanced data set, however false positives are much more costly than false negatives. Let's just say that an FP is in general 3 times more costly than an FN and the response variable = 1 means a positive identification. How should I set the class_weight parameter in sklearn's RandomForest to reflect this ? From my understanding, I would say:

```
class_weight = {0:1.0,1:3.0}
```

I'm not sure if I understand this parameter correctly or should it be the inverse ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
- &(1) &(0) \\
\hline
(1) &- &FP\\
\hline
(0) &FN &-\\
\hline
\end{array}

*Rows elements are Y_true and column is Y_pred.*

FP means, we predicted Positive and it came out False *i.e. Class was Negative(0 here)*.

It means we don't want the Model to mis-classify the Negative class.

So, it implies, we will put a bigger penalty for the Negative class. Hence,

`class_weight = {0:3.0.0,1:1.0}`